# Jquery Drop Down Menu Error

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menú you can see in the next example:

http://jsfiddle.net/WYMzX/1/

If I doing enter hover over **submenu** and after I go out from **submenu** working fine, but if I doing hover over **"Menú"** button and after I left or go out over the **Menú** button with mouse, **the submenu is still open! :( and not working fine for me**

I want that if I leave the menú or submenú the sumenú is closed.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using JavaScript rather than just CSS to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had a few problems there

1 - You needed to set a width for the top level item - without a width it was filling the whole width of the screeen - which was why it wasn;t clearing the style.

2 - jquery hover can clear itself without the need to mouseleave

3 - the use of spans isn't really necessary, apply your classes to you li and a tags and you're fine.

here's the working fiddle.

by the way, you can do all of this with pure css, but i've edited your example as I thought you might want to add transition animations or something.

http://jsfiddle.net/WYMzX/4/

---------------EDIT--------------

here's a version that uses pure css for you, all you need to do is add

```
  ul#topnav li:hover .submenu{
  display: block!important;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zandergrin/WYMzX/6/

Comment: Thank you for me working fine with Jquery. With Css not working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works fine

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("ul#topnav li a.dropdown").hover(function() {
    $("ul#topnav li ul.submenu").show(0);

});

$("ul#topnav li ul.submenu").hover(function() {
    $("ul#topnav li a.dropdown").addClass('top_nav_li_a_hover');

});


$("ul#topnav li").mouseleave (function() {


    $("ul#topnav li ul.submenu").hide(0);    
    $("ul#topnav li a.dropdown").removeClass('top_nav_li_a_hover');   

});


   });
```

it is the same code as u have used i just replaced `$("ul#topnav li ul.submenu").mouseleave`  with `$("ul#topnav li").mouseleave`

try this on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kamranali/WYMzX/5/)

Comment: yes i tried and you should also try first. try to go below 1st submenu.

Comment: `$("ul#topnav").mouseleave` try this it surely works

http://jsfiddle.net/kamranali/WYMzX/10/